# Dictionary of the first and last element of a list from a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have done this code:

```
def value(filename):
    f=open(filename,'r')

    bat_val={}

    for line in f:
        four_vals = line.split()
    return four_vals

    batch = four_vals[0]
   
    x=four_vals[1]
    y=four_vals[2]

    for x,y in four_vals:
        circle = x**2 + y**2
        if circle <= 1:
            value = four_vals[3]
            return value
        bat_val= {batch:value} 
    return bat_val


    print(value('file))
```

the consits of 9 rows with four index in each line. I want to make a dictionary of the first element(key) and the last element (value) of all lines if the second (x) and the third elements fulfil the if-statement. But it doesnt work, and i cant see whats going wrong. My output is just  the entire last line.

```
Ex:
1, 0.5, 0.5, 55
2, 0,4, 0,1 10
3, 0.9, 0.8 5
```

and i want to get  `{1:55, 2:10}`, the third line wont be included cause the if-statement is not fulfilled.

Comment: Does your work well? You return your code several time then how you expect this `print(value('file))`  should print?

Comment: the `return` statement after the first `for` loop is preventing your code from running past it. In essence, you're reasigning `four_vals` many times, and simply returning the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Not sure what you're trying to do, but proposing edits that vandalize other people's answers is definitely not in line with this site's [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Please refrain from doing this again.

Comment: it almost works. It just does not loop through all lines though..

Answer (score 0):

```
    for line in f:
        four_vals = line.split()
    return four_vals
```

Your function ends when hits a `return` statement, in this case, the one above.
In your case `four_vals` gets overwritten on each iteration of your loop and then gets returned (and it's equal to `line.split()` of the last line of the file).

Also when you open a file like this `f=open(filename,'r')` you should also close it, or use a context manager.

Comment: it almost works. It just does not loop through all lines though..

Answer (score 0):

The statement `return four_vals` is preventing your code from running past that point

```py
def value(filename):
    f=open(filename,'r') 

    bat_val={} 

    for line in f:
        four_vals = line.split()
    return four_vals
    
    # nothing past this point matters in the function

print(value('file'))
```

To accomplish what you originally wanted, you can do something like this:

```py
def value(filename):
    f=open(filename,'r') 

    bat_val={} 

    for line in f:
        four_vals = line.split(',')
        batch = four_vals[0]
        x=float(four_vals[1])
        y=float(four_vals[2])

        circle = x**2 + y**2
        if circle <= 1:
            value = four_vals[3]
            bat_val[batch] = value
    f.close()
    return bat_val

print(value('file'))
```

Some extra notes, make sure that the file you're reading is the format you want, decimal points are defined with points rather than commas, and in this case I'd recommend using `split` with commas instead of spaces.

Comment: it almost works. It just does not loop through all lines though...

Comment: Can you provide an example of a file that fails with the suggested code? I can't see a reason why it wouldn't iterate for every line in the file.